# How to update chat view smoothly when I get new message

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, tableview

I have a question about my chat app.
And I have a view about chatting to others.

[chat view like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln9ur.png)

But when others send message to me, I should update my view to let user knows new message text,I also save message in my sqlite.
And I update view in main thread when user gets message.
It makes view a while locked, and I want to send message to my chat target,I should wait the view updating to end.
In general, How to deal with updating chat view?
Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var subscribe:Disposable? 
    var texts:[Message] = [Message]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.subscribe = chatroom.PublishSubject<Any>().subscribe({ json in

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.loadTexts()
       }
    })
   } 


   func loadTexts() {

        self.texts.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        self.chatroom.messages.forEach({ (id,message) in
            self.texts.append(message)
        })

        self.texts.sort(by: { (a,b) in
            a.time < b.time
        })

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        //updateViewFrame()
        if self.texts.count > 0 {
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: self.texts.count-1,section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
        }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return texts.count
}

}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.chatTableView.dataSource = self
                self.chatTableView.delegate = self
                self.chatTableView.reloadData()
                self.tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: false)
            }

Answer (score 0):

All UI-related work must always be run in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async() {
  print("Work Dispatched")
  // Do heavy or time consuming work

  // Then return the work on the main thread and update the UI
  DispatchQueue.main.async() {
       // Return data and update on the main thread, all UI calls should be on the main thread 
      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.chatTableView.dataSource = self
                self.chatTableView.delegate = self
                self.chatTableView.reloadData()
                self.tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: false)
            }
}
```